# Explicit homotopy equivalence

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Assume $K\subseteq X$ is a non-empty contractible subspace of a topological space $X$. Let $x\in K$ be any point. I am trying to define an explicit homotopy equivalence between $X \setminus K$ and $X\setminus \{x\}$. How would I go about doing this? Thanks for your help^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. Let $X = [0,1], K = [0,1/2]$ and $x = 1/2$.

Comment: But $0\notin K$?

Comment: @Margaret My mistake. Example corrected.

Comment: I see, thanks. A generalization of your example (for any $n\geq 1$): $X=[0,1]^n$, $K=\{1/2\}\times [0,1]^{n-1}$ and $x=(1/2,\ldots,1/2)$.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4777637/an-application-of-excision) is a follow-up question. Maybe of interest to you.