# An application of excision

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $m\geq 1$ and $K\subseteq \mathring{\mathbb{D}^m}$ a convex, compact subset. Here $\mathring{\mathbb{D}^m}$ is the interior of the m-dimensional disk. Let $x\in K$.

I am trying to argue that for $q\geq 0$ we have $$H_q(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^m\setminus K)\cong H_q(\mathring{\mathbb{D}^m}, \mathring{\mathbb{D}^m}\setminus x).$$

By excision it holds that $H_q(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^m\setminus K)\cong H_q(\mathring{\mathbb{D}^m}, \mathring{\mathbb{D}^m}\setminus K)$. Now I am trying to argue that $H_q(\mathring{\mathbb{D}^m}, \mathring{\mathbb{D}^m}\setminus K)\cong H_q(\mathring{\mathbb{D}^m}, \mathring{\mathbb{D}^m}\setminus x)$. Why does that hold?
I thought that I could note that $\mathring{\mathbb{D}^m}\setminus x \simeq \mathring{\mathbb{D}^m}\setminus K$ and then use the long exact sequence for a triple. But this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4777619/explicit-homotopy-equivalence/4777625?noredirect=1#comment10152401_4777625) makes me sceptical that $\mathring{\mathbb{D}^m}\setminus x$ and $\mathring{\mathbb{D}^m}\setminus K$ are homotopy equivalent.

Comment: Of course they are homotopy equivalent in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the long exact sequence of a pair strategy, one would specifically need the inclusion $D^\circ_m\setminus K\to D^\circ_m\setminus\{x\}$ to be a homotopy equivalence. Well, one could replace $x$ with any point $x'$ of $K$ via a homeomorphism $D^\circ_m\setminus\{x\}\cong D^\circ_m\setminus\{x'\}$. If $x'$ is chosen to be an interior point of $K$ then one can simply use a radial contraction $D^\circ_m\setminus K\simeq D^\circ_m\setminus\{x'\}$. Because $K$ is compact convex with an interior point, its boundary is a sphere of the correct dimension and there is a continuous retraction $D^\circ_m\setminus\{x'\}\to D^\circ_m\setminus K$ which projects the points of $K$ onto the boundary using the line of sight from $x'$.

I confess that that is handwavy and without clear details. I am tired. On that note, I also have to confess *that if $K$ has empty interior it is not obvious to me how to procure a homotopy equivalence here*. If we could show that compact convex subsets of $D^\circ_m$ with empty interior are necessarily homeomorphic to disks of a lower dimension, this would be sufficient to conclude by a homology argument similar to the one below <s>but I don't know whether or not that is true</s>. [Allegedly this is true](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1945527). In which case there is a simple homology argument for this given in the final paragraph of this post.

---

Just for fun, here's how to do all of this without needing to figure out whether or not $D^\circ_m\setminus K\simeq D^\circ_m\setminus\{x\}$. I assume $m\ge1$. Assume first $K$ has nonempty interior.

Embed $\Bbb R^m$ into $S^m$ with stereographic projection. There is an LES: $$\cdots\to H_{q+1}(S^m;\Bbb R^m)\to H_q(\Bbb R^m;\Bbb R^m\setminus K)\to H_q(S^m;\Bbb R^m\setminus K)\to H_q(S^m;\Bbb R^m)\to\cdots$$

Observe that $S^m$ is covered by the open sets (using compactness of $K$) $S^m\setminus\{p\}=\Bbb R^m$ and $S^m\setminus K$, where $p$ is the projection point. Since $K$ is contained in the image of $\Bbb R^m$ (within $S^m$) the boundary is "good" and since $K$ is compact convex its boundary is congruent to $S^{m-1}$ and the generalised Schoenflies theorem kicks in to say $S^m\setminus K$ is a disk.

$H_j(S^m;\Bbb R^m)\cong\widetilde{H_j}(S^m)$ is easy to show. Therefore an application of Mayer-Vietoris shows the map $H_q(S^m;\Bbb R^m\setminus K)\to H_q(S^m;\Bbb R^m)$ is an isomorphism when $q\neq m$ and if $q=m$ then we have $H_m(S^m;\Bbb R^m\setminus K)\cong\Bbb Z^2$ in such a way that the map $H_m(S^m;\Bbb R^m\setminus K)\to H_m(S^m;\Bbb R^m)$ is the projection. Our LES then implies  $H_q(\Bbb R^m;\Bbb R^m\setminus K)$ is zero when $q\neq m$, and when $q=m$ $H_q(\Bbb R^m;\Bbb R^m\setminus K)\cong\ker(\Bbb Z^2\twoheadrightarrow\Bbb Z)\cong\Bbb Z$. And it's very easy to show $H_q(D^m;D^m\setminus\{x\})\cong\widetilde{H_{q-1}}(S^{m-1})\cong\widetilde{H_q}(S^m)$ so - we are done, for the case where $K$ has interior.

In the case of empty interior, if we assume $K$ has to be a disk (of lower dimension) then we can conclude as follows; $H_q(\Bbb R^m;\Bbb R^m\setminus K)\cong\widetilde{H_{q-1}}(\Bbb R^m\setminus K)\cong H_q(S^m\setminus K;\Bbb R^m\setminus K)\cong H_q(S^m;\Bbb R^m)\cong\widetilde{H_q}(S^m)$ where the last isomorphisms follow from excision, the long exact sequence of a pair. <s>But again, I don't know if $K$ is necessarily a disk or not, that's just conjecture on my part. It's true for $m=2$ :)</s>

Answer (score 0):

This exhibits why you need the requirement $K\subset\operatorname{int}{(D^m)}$ (i.e. $K$ does not touch the boundary of the disk). Now you can write an explicit homotopy equivalence $\operatorname{int}{(D^m)}\setminus K\to\operatorname{int}{(D^m)}\setminus x$.